# Webpart to search a Items in a list Sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, search-box

Is a Sharepoint 2013 has got a Search box to search items on the list. How to add this kind of webpart. Can be dowload if Yes so from where ? I must to have a textbox where I type a text and it search me worker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved in many ways. By default your options would be to use an OOTB web part called Text Filter Web Part **or** to add your list to the page, and from the web part's properties > *Miscellaneous* > activate *Display search box*.

Depending on your page's setup, activated site (collection) features and such, these mentioned options might not be available for you, or they are just not good enough. Like for example the Text Filter WP requires the text to match exactly the item's name by default.

If your requirement is higher, you should use the SharePoint REST API. An excellent guide for this has been written by Mark Rackley. See [WHO NEEDS A DATA VIEW WEB PART? SHAREPOINT REST AND DATATABLES.NET](https://info.summit7.us/blog/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net) article.

Comment: And where Can I find this ?

Comment: I don't see this filter category on Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Assuming you have SharePoint **Enterprise** which is required, check that that you have activated _SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features_ from _Site collection features_. Next check that they are activated in your _Site features_.

Comment: I haven't got any activate Display search box on Miscellaneous

Comment: _Display search box_ is available if you have added the list as an application to your page (Page -> Edit page -> Insert -> App Part -> Select your list you'd like to search). It's not available on for example Content Query web parts etc.

Comment: Great Fenks Moe :) I Find a Filters and more :)

Comment: Text Filters doesn't allow me to connect to my Form Libraries. The Search Box doesn't work on my form libraries when they're in Group By mode.

Comment: I am having the issue of the web part not keeping the 'Display search box' property. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @wayzz I recommend you to make a separate question about this. Please describe at least the following: are the changes visible only in edit mode or for how long are they visible, have you activated the SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features, are you trying to add the property to the app of a list or a library and which SharePoint version you are running (SP2013/2010/O365).

Comment: @wayzz Be aware of the bug from M$ that if there are two OOTB search boxes in the same page, the second one won't work.

Comment: is it possible to make the view load items only on search and not on page load?

Comment: @vignesh you could by default hide the results with css and have them appear once search is done. One way of doing it: `$("#searchArea").on("keyup", "#searchBox", function(){ $('#searchResults').fadeIn("900"); });`

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to search items in a SharePoint list and the list search box doesn't appear for you? There is a web part property called "Display Search Box" that enables this. It should be on by default.

Or are you trying to add a search box to the page that will search other content?
You can add a Search Box web part to any page. How you would configure it depends on the type of content your are trying to search.

Comment: But how configure them ?

Comment: I want only search a text first of all Text on a list.

Comment: This doesn't work on my Form Library that has grouping/group by enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a search box on your page and search in a particular list/library ? If yes, here is something you can do..http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013office-365-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx

Comment: I must always do a source to the list ? It's not easest things to do this ?

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Add the details to your answer, and use the link as a source.

Answer (score 0):

If the Style of the View of a list that's a web part on a page is not set to Default (but, for instance, Shaded instead), then "Display Search Box" will not be available under Miscellaneous in the web part edit control panel.