# How to limit Search Webpart to specified custom lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to use the OOBE Search / Search Results Web Apps to search specified Custom Lists and not the entire Site?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what the code would need to look like for a list called "Client" I am still learning to script and this would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This thread may help - [Webpart to search a Items in a list Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110674/webpart-to-search-a-items-in-a-list-sharepoint-2013)

I use this bit of code to make my own.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

// Search for the terms when the Search button is clicked

function customSearch(inputId,type,site,scope) {

    var searchUrl = site + "Pages/searchresults.aspx?" // Or "/_layouts/SearchResults.aspx?" if WSS 2003 or SP2010 Foundation
    var searchTerm = "&k=" + document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    var listParams = "&cs=This%20" + type + "&u=" + scope;
    window.location.href = searchUrl + searchTerm + listParams;
}

// Initiate the customSearch function when the Enter key is pressed

function searchKeyPress(buttonId,e) {
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    if (window.event) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
    }
}

// ]]></script><strong><br/></strong><span class="ms-rteFontFace-12 ms-rteFontSize-5 ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0"><span class="textItem ms-rteFontFace-12 ms-rteFontSize-5 ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0">Custom Search</span></span><br/><input name="searchBox4" id="searchBox4" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(&#39;searchButton4&#39;,event);" type="text"/><input name="searchButton4" id="searchButton4" onclick="customSearch( &#39;searchBox4&#39;, &#39;List&#39;, &#39;https://sharepoint.com/site/&#39;, &#39;https://sharepoint.com/site/Lists/customlist&#39; );" type="button" value="Search"/><br/>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the code would need to look like for a list called "Client" I am still learning to script and this would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, The standard functionality is to tell a search what to look for. make a new page, make some refiner for it that is used on your custom list and viola you can search on a specific list. so you get people, everything, "your own custom search", etc.
It takes some configuring but it is possible.