# List View Search Box - always use wildcard

Tags: search, list-view

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 on-premise and Sharepoint Online.
Is it possible to set Search Box to use wildcard on all requests, not only with '**' in it?
Basically, I want users to have wildcard search without knowing it.
I also need search on all fields in a current view.
I've tried all search webparts that SharePoint offer, but none of them works in that way. I'm thinking of adding '*' to search box on keyup event but maybe there's a more elegant solution?

Comment: The more elegant way is to use SharePoint's REST API. I have an ancient answer [over here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110674/webpart-to-search-a-items-in-a-list-sharepoint-2013/110677#110677) to get you started.

Comment: Displaying search results in List View Web Part is what troubles me while using custom search request